# Application Localization (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have code to check for insertion only from digits.

How can I translate ": can not be pasted" using Localizable.strings?

```
let pastAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Past",comment: ""), style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        if UIPasteboard.general.string?.onlyNumbers() == "" {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Calc Pro", message: "\(UIPasteboard.general.string ?? ""): cannot be pasted", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)
            alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 235/255, green: 92/255, blue: 48/255, alpha: 1)
            print("Cannot be pasted")
        } else {
            self.displayResultLabel.text = UIPasteboard.general.string
            print("Pasted")
        }
    })
```

Comment: Scan [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+NSLocalizedString+variable) for more solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use String interpolation for NSLocalizedString as well.
Like this:

```
"\(UIPasteboard.general.string ?? "") \(NSLocalizedString(": cannot be pasted", comment: ""))"
```

EDIT: But as @rmmady suggested, when using localized strings with variables, the proper way to handle it is to let your localized string to accept variables

Example:

```
"%@: cannot be pasted" = "%@ : cannot be pasted"
```

and call it as follows

```
String(format: NSLocalizedString("%@: cannot be pasted", comment: ""), "Your variable here")
```

Comment: Thanks, it works))

Comment: No, this is not the proper way to do localization with variables. What if in some languages the string needs to go in a different location within the message?

Comment: i agree with you @rmaddy but I think that's why he is using "**:**" to prevent the confusion regarding different language to happen

Comment: i will edit my answer as well to be more accurate